# Azure ADF V2 ForEach File CopyData from Blob Storage to SQL Table

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I need to design an ADF pipeline to copy a CSV file created on a particular Blob Store folder path named "Current" to a SQL table. After successful copy, i'll have to move the file to an archive folder.

**Things i've accomplished**: I'm using a Copy Data Activity that copies the CSV file and loads into my SQL table. On success, another copy data activity will copy the CSV file from "Current" folder to "Archive", after this i have a Delete activity that deletes the file from Current  Folder.

**Issue**: This is totally fine where there is only one file at a time. But i want redesign this to handle multiple files imports. I want make use of ForEach activity. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a Get Metadata activity before the for-each.  The Get Metadata activity will get the files in the current directory and pass them to the For-Each.  You connect it to your Blob storage folder and specify the file mask.   The output of the activity will need to be the input for your for-each loop.  Something like this..@activity('Get Metadata').output.
  By the way how are you triggering this ADF pipeline?  Another way to accomplish this would be to setup an event trigger to run this pipeline whenever a file is created in that blob directory.
  Here are the steps to use the For-Each on files in a storage container.

1. Set the Get Metadata argument to "Child Items"
   [image: child_items-screenshot]
2. In your For-Each set the Items to @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems

[image: for-each-image]

3. In the Source Dataset used in your Copy Activity create a parameter named FileName.

[image: filename Parameter]

4. Set the file path to use the parameter
   [image: file path parameter]
5. On the Copy Activity set the FileName parameter to @item().name
   [image]

To finish you'll need to set the sink to whatever you need.  That should do it.

Comment: It is worth noting that the GetMetadata activity is limited to just 1 Mb of data, and if you have thousands of files (or kind of long names) in that folder it will throw an error. A much better approach would be to just use wildcard file filters in the blob storage dataset. This way you just do a regular copy activity. More info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/data-factory-supports-wildcard-file-filter-for-copy-activity/

Comment: Event Trigger - Whenever a new file is created in the folder the adf triggers. if there are two files then there will be two concurrent execution. As i'm currently moving the entire folder from current to archive, either of the concurrent execution will fail as the other one already moved the file process

Comment: @MartinEstebanZurita most scenarios only one file is created, but in very rare situation multiple files will be created.

Comment: @Nate - i was able to add a GetMetaData with Child Items and FilterFile activity(FilterFile to get only the file types) and feeding the output of FilterFile to the forEach activity. but now i'm not sure how to feed the unique file name as the source for the copy activity. Can I put the output of the FilterFile to a adf parameter and feed the parameter value for the copy activity ?

Comment: @gopinath  I added step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your step by step instruction. I just figured I can also use @item().name and wanted to update the answer but saw that you already did. Awesome.

Comment: When using this method the copy activity fails the path is not resolving the @item().name Hot/2021/04/@{@item()} .. any ideas?

Comment: @Nate - do you happen to know how I would filter out the @item().name to just pull files that have a *.txt extension?