# Passing File names from Foreach to Data Flow - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read ADLS files in a directory, read the content of the file, do some processing and store the file in adls but the destination file name will depend on one of the column values of input file.

To start with, this is my flow:
[image]

Inside Metadata:

[image]

Inside Foreach:

[image]

I am triggering a Mapping Data Flow inside ForEach activity:

[image]

My Mapping data flow inside ForEach :

[image]

Source settings of Mapping data flow:

[image]
[image]

Inside Metadata container dataset :

[image]

Filename is not getting resolved. I am getting the error message :

[image]

I am not sure if I am missing anything. Can any help. Thanks.

Note: I have referred this post too. Thanks
[Azure ADF V2 ForEach File CopyData from Blob Storage to SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635685/azure-adf-v2-foreach-file-copydata-from-blob-storage-to-sql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.
I gave the full path in wildcard as below:

[image]

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are absolutely right. Add to yours answer. Have you set the value of sink **File Name** text field. So that it will create the same file in the target file folder.
[image]

It's value was set previous in the Foreach activity:
[image]

---

**update:**
What's yours **Data preview** looks like?
[image]

Comment: Thanks Joseph. But my DestFileName is from the input file data.

Comment: I have another doubt. I was expected one column _col0) like your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616825/converting-fixed-width-file-to-delimited-file-in-azure-data-factory-mapping-da, But I am getting Column0, column1, Column2. How can i take all the values as single column

Comment: Do you mean that you continue the previous experiment on this basis?

Comment: In my source files(txt file) there just have one column, do you have sevral columns in your soure files and what's the file type?  I've combined the previous and current experiments and it works well.

Comment: This file also a fixed width file and i m not getting _col0_ as the column name. I m getting multiple column names even after specifying no column delimiter in source settings.

Comment: What's yours Data preview looks like? Please see my updated part of my answer. You'd better give another question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220834/discussion-between-madan-and-joseph-xu).