# Copying files (using wildcard) and add timestamp to the file names

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity in ADF that copies files using wildcard paths (*.csv -> 20210102_f1.csv, 20210102_f2.csv) into Sink dataset. When it copies the files, I would like them to have a timestamp yyyyMMddhhmmss before the extension name e.g. 20210102_f1_20210202101521.csv.

Is this possible in ADF - copying with wildcards and adding timestamp to target files (all at once, not doing foreach for each of the file and affixing the timestamp)?

Comment: Do you know what the filenames will contain upfront, or can it be anything?

Comment: it can be anything

Comment: ideally, it can be anything. but if there's no other way, im willing to explore specific filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the filename, you can use this in Sink dataset filename:

`@concat('20210102_f1_',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'dd-MM-yyy'),'.csv')`

If you still want to loop through every file in folder you can use solution from this thread:

[Azure ADF V2 ForEach File CopyData from Blob Storage to SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635685/azure-adf-v2-foreach-file-copydata-from-blob-storage-to-sql-table)

Basically you need to get filenames into data factory variables, to use source filename in this dynamic destination filename solution.